# getCanonicalPath returns a different path between different platforms

Tags: java, file

One of the lower methods in my code is getting the canonical path to the temp folder using the `file.getCanonicalPath()` function (File was defined as `File file = new File("/tmp")`). This works in linux and windows OS's, but on macOS, this function returns the following string - "/private/tmp" even though I have a tmp folder in my home directory and I don't have /private directory. 
Any idea where does this "private" directory is coming from and why this method is not directing me to "/tmp" in macOS even though its accessible?

Note: if I create a random, non- existing dir File object (`File file = new File("/random")`) it will return the canonical path just fine.

Comment: that is a symlink...

Answer (score 1):

> A symbolic link, also termed a soft link, is a special kind of file
>   that points to another file, much like a shortcut in Windows or a
>   Macintosh alias. Unlike a hard link, a symbolic link does not contain
>   the data in the target file. It simply points to another entry
>   somewhere in the file system.

On macOS `/tmp` is symlinked to `/private/tmp`. The directory `/private` **does** exist and contains `tmp` inside it.

Comment: Ok.. that seems like a step in the right direction but the error that I get is still: Folder not exist: /private/tmp

Comment: See [File#createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))